# Is that possible to show that there is 0 rows of specified criteria with UNION and COUNT() usage?

Tags: sql, hive, bigdata

my table: "tfr_general_charges" has a column called MANDANT_ID. The column can have only two different values: 
001 and 002
There are many records with the value 002 in MANDANT_ID column and my SELECT shows it as follows:

[image]

I marked red the missing row, which also has to be displayed. So far, it has been returning number of rows with MANDANT_ID = '002', but zero rows with MANDANT_ID '001' should also be visible.
Here is my code:

```
SELECT
    "tfr_gen_ch" AS tabnam
    , run_date
    , mandant_id
    , count(*) as total
FROM tfr_general_charges
GROUP BY
    run_date
    , mandant_id
having mandant_id = '002'
union
SELECT
    "tfr_gen_ch" AS tabnam
    , run_date
    , mandant_id
    , count(*) as total
FROM tfr_general_charges
GROUP BY
    run_date
    , mandant_id
having mandant_id = '001'
```

In addition, I work with HIVE SQL and tried to use ISNULL() function, but without success.
Can You please help?

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION ALL` to create a resultset with only 2 rows with 1 column containing the values `'001'` and `'002'` and do a `LEFT` join to your table before you aggregate:

```
SELECT "tfr_gen_ch" tabnam, 
       tcg.run_date,
       t.mandant_id, 
       COUNT(tcg.mandant_id) AS total
FROM (SELECT '001' AS mandant_id UNION ALL SELECT '002') t
LEFT JOIN tfr_general_charges tcg
ON t.mandant_id = tcg.mandant_id
GROUP BY tcg.run_date, t.mandant_id;
```

Comment: I think You made a typo: there should be COUNT(tcg.mandant_id) instead of COUNT(c.mandant_id), but Your code is valid anyway. Thank You for this tip!

Comment: @adann96d of course, thanks. I edited.